# How to indicate right PHP path?

Tags: php

I have some confusion to indicate files path in php `require_once()`

This is my Document structure:

```
httpdocs/
         |- includes/ 
         |          |- footer.php
         |          |- header.php
         |
         |
         |- signin/   config/
         |        |         |- membersite_config.php
         |        |
         |        |- access.php
         |        |- login.php
         |        |- login-home.php
         |        |- page3.php
         |
         |- index.php
         |- page1.php
         |- page2.php
```

This is my existing code of `index.php` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php
$page_title = "page title | site name";
$page_description = "page description";
?>

<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

<body>
 Page body

<?php include("includes/footer.php");?>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to add this code on the top of `index.php` file. It is showing 500-error although same code is working fine on `page3.php`
please assist me to write the exact path.

```
//I need to add this code with correct path.

<?PHP
require_once("signin/config/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("signin/login.php");
exit;
}
?>

//existing code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php
$page_title = "page title | site name";
$page_description = "page description";
?>

<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

<body>
 Page body

<?php include("includes/footer.php");?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks correct, are there any issues?

Comment: @Hanky Panky It is showing "500-Internal server error."

Comment: It is an internal server error, not document error

Comment: @Steven Dropper : When I add same code on "page3.php" , it is working fine. because that page located in the same directory.

Comment: Check your error log, it will tell you what the problem is

Comment: "page3.php" is in signin/config ??

Comment: @Jeff : Yes!!! "page3.php" is in signin/config.

Comment: @sanzuu have you tried echoing out the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] path to see if you can use that? You may be able to use it like this
`require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/signin/config/membersite_config.php");`
It's a little hacky but it might sort your issue.
**Edit:** [$_SERVER php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: @d3v_1 : this code is not working in my case.

Comment: Very strange. As per @rjdown's comment, check your error logs. There might be something else going on.

Comment: Try to make use of `__DIR__` too http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: @rjdown : Like this `require_once __DIR__ . '/signin/config/membersite_config.php';`  ??

Comment: Looks good, give it a go!

Comment: @rjdown : Not working , Error-500 !!

Comment: Then you really need to check your error logs.

Comment: @rjdown : Where is the "Error logs" in Godaddy 's Parallels Plesk -Windows Hosting ?

Comment: Not sure, best to ask their support team

Comment: @rjdown : Its OK..